# Codeigniter url creation for newly added product in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I recently started developing with CI(3) and pretty new to MVC.

I am stuck to a point where I don't know where to stat from. I have successfully created template, login & registration system, database and product insert script. And it does insert the fields in database.

Now my problem is how to go about giving an auto generated url for newly added product and I can't seem to find information about it.

Seeking your help.

Comment: you may provide some of your code and also, what is it that you exactly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function in your controller something like this:

```
function view($product_id){
   // load your model
  $this->load->model('model_name');
  //get data from database, using your model.
  $query = $this->model_name->get_details($product_id);
  if($query){
    $data['details'] = $query;
  }
  $this->load->view('view_name',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto generated URL ?

I assume you have an auto increment ID in your database table.
The usual way is to just use it to build unique URLs.

Example:

```
 /posts/unique_id_from_database
```

Then whenever you want to display links to your posts, you can query them from the database and build the strings :

```
$link = 'posts/'.$results['id'];
```

Then you use a function like @Dray provided to load them when displaying the posts themselves.